# stuck at uploading images of different extensions in php

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have trouble uploading .png and .bmp extensions while other extensions work fine

```
$allowed_types = array(".gif" , ".jpg" , ".jpeg", ".png" , ".bmp");
$fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$f_ext = substr($fname, strripos($fname, '.'));
$f_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

if (in_array($f_ext,$allowed_types) && ($f_size < 50000))
    {   
        // upload
    } else { 
        //error
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Jpg works, gif works, jpeg works, but png and bmp won't.

Comment: Seems like it should work fine unless the case of your file name is different from the array, there's a space somehow making its way in, or the image doesn't actually have the proper extension. Try a `var_dump` to see what's coming across.

Comment: By "*won't work*" are we to assume you mean `//error` is reached? Are you sure your `.bmp` and `.png` files aren't failing with your `$f_size < 50000` condition? Remove that condition and try again.

Comment: Could it be that your BMP and PNG images have uppercase letters in their filename extensions? You probably want to allow that in any case, so you might try: strtolower($f_ext)

Comment: It could also be the Server Apache/NGINX or PHP max allowed file size to upload is not greater than the file size you are trying to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. My first response was a bit hasty. I always exclude the dot in my extension checks.

```
$allowed_types = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/bmp', 'image/x-windows-bmp'); 
$allowed_exts = array('gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'bmp'); 

$img_info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
$f_type = image_type_to_mime_type($img_info[2]); // file type
$f_ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'], '.'), 1)); // file extension
$f_size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

IF ( (in_array($f_ext, $allowed_exts)) && (in_array($f_type, $allowed_types)) && ($f_size <= 50000) ) {  
    // upload

} else { 
    //error
    die('<pre>Error!<br>Size: '.$f_size.'<br>Extension: '.$f_ext.'<br>Mime: '.$f_type.'</pre>');
}
```

Also, MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field. Php should be configured to allow the filesize as well.