# How do i get only the first part of the MIME type in PHP

Tags: php, mime-types

I would only like to know if a file is an image, a video or another type of file. The file does not exist on the server, as it is being uploaded.

Is there a way to get this in PHP?

Thank you

Comment: it's just a string. `explode('/', 'video/mp4')[0]`

Comment: Ok, thank you Marc, i thought maybe it was another data type

Comment: when in doubt, `var_dump($whatever)` will tell you what it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957923/stuck-at-uploading-images-of-different-extensions-in-php/36958333#36958333

Answer (score 0):

```
$mime = explode('/', mime_content_type($physicalPathForTheFile));
$type = $mime[0];
```